# How to remove dried latex paint out of painter whites

Tags: painting

I'm a professional painter by trade and sometimes a spill happens and it gets paint on my work pants. How can I remove at least some of it with a home remedy? My painters paints cost $20 to $30 a pair and I have to look somewhat professional and clean so if I can get some of the paint out so I don't have to keep buying painters whites, it would save me a ton of money each year.

I have a brand new pair I destroyed yesterday when my fall protection lanyard rubbed on some wet Shercryl and now my new pants are ruined. Any good ideas would be highly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I always assumed the more paint colors on a painters' pants the busier he/she was. Which translates to him/her being a better painter.

Comment: The reason you wear painters whites is so that you can *get paint on them and not your good clothes*. ( non work clothes ) Paint them white once in while.  Can a painter without paint on their pants be trusted?

Answer (score 1):

Lucky you. I've had to try to clean spots out with $80/gal reducer.

When I work in such a readily available and cheap solvent, I take the garment off immediately, get the whole garment soaking wet, work it in a sink if possible, and bag it.  Then wash it within 8 hours or so.  Should recover nicely.

Letting it dry is the mistake. This wrecks the fibers. You'll never get dried paint of of the fibers.

Answer (score 0):

> Alcohol is a well-known
>   cleaning agent for dried latex paint. The solvents in commercial latex
>   paint removers are various types of alcohols, but you can use
>   isopropyl -- or rubbing -- alcohol as well as denatured alcohol from
>   the paint store. You may also have luck removing dried paint stains
>   from furniture and floors using a dilute solution of ammonia and
>   water. Moreover, soap and water often help loosen the bond of the
>   paint from the surface it's adhered to when you want to remove the
>   paint.
>
> Always test the solvent you're going to use on the
>   substrate to which the paint adheres before using it, to make sure it
>   won't damage the finish or the surface itself. This is particularly
>   important if you're trying to remove paint from plastic. If the
>   solvent is safe, you can proceed.

https://www.hunker.com/13423915/how-to-remove-dry-latex-paint